# Как работает строчка кода?

Tags: c++

Вообще не понимаю как работает "word[i] != word[len-i-1]".
Пожалуйста, опишите как можно подробнее и "для чайников")

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возьмите ручку, бумажку и напишите строку, а потом посмотрите на какие символы указывает  `word[len-i-1]`. Вы увидите, что это `i-ый` с конца символ

Comment: Какой именно элемент `word[i] != word[len-i-1]` вызывает у вас затруднения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(a != b)` истинно, когда a не равно b

`word[i]` - это i-й с начала символ строки

`word[len-i-1]` - это i-й с конца символ строки

таким образом `word[i] != word[len-i-1]` проверяет на неравенство i-й с начала символ строки и i-й с конца символ строки.

Comment: Спасибо, это я понял, но почему именно [len-i-1] - это конец строки?

Comment: конец строки - это word[len-1] (т.к. в строке len элементов, а нумерация начинается с 0).

Comment: word[len-1-1] - это второй с конца, word[len-1-2] - третий с конца и тд